# Creating a single perceptron for training

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, neural-network, jupyter-notebook

learning how perceptron works and attempted to created a function out of it.

I recently watched a video in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzWaow1Rvho&list=PLxt59R_fWVzT9bDxA76AHm3ig0Gg9S3So) as an introduction to the said topic.

Right now, I tried to mimic his function and I would like to try applying it in a sample dataset:

```
#         x1    x2  y
data = [ [3.5, 1.5, 1],
         [2.0, 1.0, 0],
         [4.0, 1.5, 1],
         [3.0, 1.0, 0],
         [3.5, 0.5, 1],
         [2.0, 0.5, 0],
         [5.5, 1.0, 1],
         [1.0, 1.0, 0],
         [4.5, 1.0, 1] ]

data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Length", "Width", "Class"])
```

Sigmoid function:

```
def sigmoid(x):
    x = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return x
```

Perceptron function:

```
w1 = np.random.randn()
w2 = np.random.randn()
b = np.random.randn()

def perceptron(x1,x2, w1, w2, b):

    z = (w1 * x1) + (w2 * x2) + b

    return sigmoid(z)
```

My question here is how can I add the cost function inside the Perceptron and loop it n times based from a parameter to adjust the weights using the cost function?

```
def get_cost_slope(b,a):
    """
    b = predicted value
    a = actual value
    """

    sqrerror = (b - a) ** 2
    slope = 2 * (b-a)

    return sqrerror, slope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a method which would backpropagate through the perceptron and optimize the weights.

```
def optimize( a , b ):

    sqrerror = (b - a) ** 2
    cost_deriv = 2 * (b-a)

    sigmoid_deriv = z * ( 1 - z ) # derivative of sigmoid function

    learning_rate = 0.001 # Used to scale the gradients

    w1 -= ( cost_deriv * sigmoid_deriv * x1 ) * learning_rate # Gradient Descent update rule
    w2 -= ( cost_deriv * sigmoid_deriv * x2 ) * learning_rate
    b -= ( cost_deriv * sigmoid_deriv ) * learning_rate
```

Since ,

[image: Partial Derivative]

Where $J$ is the cost function.